# C++ : Error while replacing character

Tags: c++, string, replace

I'm trying to replace ";" in a string with a substring on which I'll split my stream later.
The problem now is with `string::replace()`. Here's the code:

```
std::string Lexer::replace(const std::string &line) const
{
  std::size_t   start_pos;
  std::string   tmp(line);

  start_pos = 0;
  while ((start_pos = tmp.find(";", start_pos)) != std::string::npos)
  {
    tmp.replace(start_pos, 1, " ");
    start_pos += 1;
  }
  return (tmp);
}
```

The `line` string could be something like : `word1 word2 word3; word1 word2 word3;...`.
It works for a string like `word1 word2 word3;`, but here's what I get for a string like `word1 word2 word3; word1 word2 word3;` :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::replace
Aborted
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I read that this error occurs when the given position in `string::replace(pos, len, substr)` is equal to `string::npos`, so why the condition in my loop doesn't help avoiding it?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to initialise `start_pos` to 0 before the start of your loop.

Comment: Where do you initialize start_pos?

Comment: Yes you're right I forgot to paste that line but I don't think it's the problem, the error still occurs. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not seem to initialize start_pos, so you would need to change this line:

```
std::size_t   start_pos = 0;
//                     ^^^^
```

Otherwise, you get undefined behavior with some garbage value potentially representing the starting position.

Also, note that you would be better off using string::size_type since you are working with string size here when iterating.

This code works fine for me:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string myreplace(const string &line)
{
    string::size_type   start_pos = 0;
    string   tmp(line);

    while ((start_pos = tmp.find(";", start_pos)) != string::npos)
    {
        tmp.replace(start_pos, 1, " ");
        start_pos += 1;
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    string test_str1 = "word1 word2 word3;";
    string test_str2 = "word1 word2 word3; word1 word2 word3;";
    string test_str3 = "word1 word2 word3; word1 word2 word3;....";

    cout << myreplace(test_str1) << endl;
    cout << myreplace(test_str2) << endl;
    cout << myreplace(test_str3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
word1 word2 word3 
word1 word2 word3  word1 word2 word3 
word1 word2 word3  word1 word2 word3 ....
```

==================================================

That being said, you should consider using the standard replace algorithm from std as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string test_str1 = "word1 word2 word3;";
    string test_str2 = "word1 word2 word3; word1 word2 word3;";
    string test_str3 = "word1 word2 word3; word1 word2 word3;....";

    string out_str1 = replace(test_str1.begin(), test_str1.end(), ';', ' ');
    string out_str2 = replace(test_str2.begin(), test_str2.end(), ';', ' ');
    string out_str3 = replace(test_str3.begin(), test_str3.end(), ';', ' ');

    cout << out_str1 << endl;
    cout << out_str2 << endl;
    cout << out_str3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
word1 word2 word3 
word1 word2 word3  word1 word2 word3 
word1 word2 word3  word1 word2 word3 ....
```

Comment: Actually it was done in my code but not here. I edited my post.

Comment: Although if the value is out of range `find` is supposed to return `npos`, so it's hard to see how the parameter to `replace` could be invalid.

Comment: @Amina: See the code, it seems to work for me. :O You are claiming that this code throws an exception for you?

Comment: @Laszlo: It works for something like `word1 word2 word3;`, but not for `word1 word2 word3; word1 word2 word3;....`, right?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Omg my bad, It works! I don't know why it didn't work the two first times ^^
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You did not initialize variable `start_pos`

```
std::size_t   start_pos;
```

So the code has undefined behaviour.

Write

```
std::size_t   start_pos = 0;
```

Also you should use correct types for variables that deal with class std::string. It would be more correctly to write

```
std::string::size_type   start_pos = 0;
```

Take into account that `size_t( -1 )` can be unequal to `std::string::size_type( -1 )` that is the definition of `std::string::npos`.

Also you could use standard algorithm `std::replace` defined in header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
std::string Lexer::replace(const std::string &line) const
{
   std::string   tmp(line);

   std::replace( tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), ';', ' ' );

   return (tmp);
}
```

**EDIT:** If the replacement consists from several characters then you can write

```
std::string Lexer::replace(const std::string &line, const char *replacement ) const
{
   std::string tmp( line );
   size_t n = std::strlen( replacement ); 

   std::string::size_type start_pos = 0;
   while ( ( start_pos = s.find( ';', start_pos ) ) != std::string::npos )
   {
      line.replace( start_pos, 1, replacement );
      start_pos += n;
   }

   return ( tmp );
}
```

Comment: Yes I read something about replace, but actually I'd prefere to replace it with another string separator and not a space.

Comment: @Amina  In this case the function has to have secons parameter that will specify the string separator.

Comment: In this case it wouldn't be useful. This is a tiny parser, I know the string separator.

Comment: @Amina See my uodated post